# Adding new sequential ID numbers based on sorted data (ArcGIS)

Tags: python, arcgis

I need a line of code that will issue new sequential id's based on the order I've prescribed to my data. Essentially, after having sorted my data to my liking, the original Object_Id's are no longer in a meaningful order to me. In my table I created a new field (short integer). In the pre logic script box of the field calculator I attempted the following:

```
counter = 0
 def uniqueID():
 global counter
 counter += 1
 return counter
```

But it didn't seem to work.. A little sample of what my table looks like is as follows: (for visualization purposes)

```
Object_ID    /    MMSI    /    TIME    /    VESSEL    /    NEW_ID

  1210            4444       01/10/10         01            NuLL
  1801            4444       02/10/10         01            NuLL
   303            4444       03/10/10         01            NuLL
  2839            4444       03/10/10         01            NuLL
 32100            5555       01/10/10         03            NuLL
    34            5555       02/10/10         03            NuLL
```

In essence I need those NuLL's to now be 1, 2, 3, 4... etc etc. as my data is now ordered to my liking (first by MMSI number/within MMSI by date)

**So, it would look as follows after:** (notice the New_ID field is now populated)

```
Object_ID    /    MMSI    /    TIME    /    VESSEL    /    NEW_ID

  1210            4444       01/10/10         01            1
  1801            4444       02/10/10         01            2
   303            4444       03/10/10         01            3
  2839            4444       03/10/10         01            4
 32100            5555       01/10/10         03            5
    34            5555       02/10/10         03            6
```

how would I accomplish this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a field calculator sample in the ArcGIS Help that does exactly what you want.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000

(If that link doesn't work for you just search for "calculate field examples" in the ArcGIS help).

Scroll down to "Accumulative and sequential calculations".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the updatecursor from the arcpy library

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("your attriubute table") 

counter = 1
for row in rows:
    row.NEW_ID = counter
    rows.updateRow(row)
    counter += 1
```

please make sure the correct data type

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the "arcpy" library and make adjustments to datasets.

Comment: use the  python console in arcmap and import the library (import arcpy)

Comment: I get an error when I try this: " The value type is incompatible with the field type". I tried double, short integer and float. What could be my error?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code (see below), but simply adds 1 to the FID value, not a serial sequence in the sorted order...

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("your attribute table") 

counter = 1
for row in rows:
    row.NEW_ID = counter
    rows.updateRow(row)
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,

I created a new field short integer
Sort the data into my desired arrangement
Export dbf as excel data, notice that it will export the way it was arranged in attribute table
Fill out the numbering in excel (you will not be able to save it since its a dbf file)
Copy the column of the sequence field in excel
Go back to your attribute table, then paste the numbering there.

It worked since there's no python code available online

Answer (score -2):

This fast solution simply uses Excel to create the sequential numbering on the sorted data, then joins the resulting table back in using ArcGIS:

1. Export your attribute table as a "Text File", being sure to add the .csv extension to the file name.
2. Open the .csv file in MS Excel.
3. Sort as desired.
4. In a new column in Excel, in row one type the number 1.
5. In row two, type the number 2.
6. Select both rows in that column and double-click the little box at bottom right of the selection to cause the numbering to continue sequentially down the column to the end of your populated rows.
7. Save the .csv.
8. Go back to ArcGIS and use "Add Data" to import the .csv you just created.
9. Right-click on the feature, select "Joins and Relates" -> "Join...".
10. Choose "Join attributes from a table".
11. Select the appropriate fields and the correct .csv file (the one you just imported)
12. Click "OK".
13. Finally, export the feature to a new feature to make the join permanent.